# Elasticsearch: Make GET request of index's fields from mapping

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to autotest some things for elastic.
One of them it's to:
1. GET all fields from mapping
2. Check that all fields are present
3. Check that fields with present **_id** in their names have type integer.
But let's get started at least with returning mappings.
I do it successfully in kibana console with

```
GET /persons/_mappings
```

But did not find any information about how to do it in requests:
Currently, I have this request:

```
let client = await connectElastic();
        const response = await client.search({
            method: 'GET',
            index: 'persons',
            // perheps here must be some parameter?
        });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using elasticsearch.js library [elasticsearch.js](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js):

first create client:

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
  host: 'localhost:9200',
  log: 'trace'
});
```

You can use this api:

```
client.indices.getMapping({ index: 'persons'}, (err, res) => {
     if (!err) {
         console.log(res);
     }
});
```

Comment: Hi Tarek. Thank you. That's exactly what I needed. I see I've read this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-indices-getmapping documentation in very "scratch the surface" manner. Need to read it thoroughly. By the way, you just missed a bit from my question. The client is already built, I don't  know why you haven't seen it and proposed me to create the client :-)

Comment: You are very welcome Alexander. I know you created the client, I just wanted to include the require of the library, link to it, and creation of the client for anyone else who need the same solution :)